# I want to have a good understanding of the use of return *this in c++

Tags: c++

I want to have a good understanding of the use of `return *this` and take of instance we have

```
coord& coord::operator=(const coord& other)
{
    if (this== &other)
}
```

My concern here is the use of `this` and the use of `return *this`

Comment: What is it that you don't understand about it? Which book are you using to learn C++?

Comment: `{ if (this== &other)}` This is not valid syntax.

Comment: What use of `return *this`? I don't see it, and I looked carefully.

Comment: check out [what is 'this'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492736/what-is-the-this-pointer) and [dereferencing a pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) and [why assignment operator is the way it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105798/why-must-the-copy-assignment-operator-return-a-reference-const-reference)

Comment: The expression `*this` represents the present class.  In the assignment idiom, you are returning an instance of the present class, after data members from the `other` class have been assigned.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  That syntax is quite correct.  Comparing pointers is a rather basic operation

Comment: OK.  if you want to split hairs...  We all got the grist of what the OP meant.

Comment: Not here to split hairs, nor to fight.  Only to help OP.

Comment: my own bad. :)  And excuse my poor second language.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
coord& coord::operator=(const coord& other) 
{ 
   // the test on adresses below is to make sure we're not doing useless work.  
   // comparing pointers is fast.
   // making sure the addresses are different, we know we are not copying
   // the object onto itself.
   // It is both an optimization, and can, for certain memory operations, avoid bugs 
   // although modern compilers do avoid the memcpy/memmove bug, which was real pain a
   // while back.  Some CPUs _will_ puke when asked to copy and source == destination.
   if (this != &other)  
   {
       // usually member-by member copy goes here.
   }

   // returning a reference is standard for copy operations.
   // it allows for such syntaxes as:
   // coord a, b, c;
   //
   // a = b = c;
   //
   // or 
   // if ((a = b) == c) {}
   //
   // etc...
   //
   return *this;  
}
```

Note: this answer only refers to the question about comparing addresses and the need to return a reference.  If your class requires memory allocation or copying any of the members may throw, you should check this post:  [1]: [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279550#3279550) as pointed out by Lightness Races in Orbit.

Comment: [That is not how we should be writing `operator=`, though](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279550/560648).

Comment: That's debatable if coordinates are like x, y, z.  Effective programming depends on context.  Will add a note.

Comment: If your class is just coordinates like x, y, z then you have no need for an `operator=` in the first place. Context is absolutely crucial, you are right about that, but these idioms develop for a reason, and are taught by the experts for a reason.

Comment: .I am personally a fan of the rule of zero.

Comment: chat for one sec?  I have an off-topic mystery that may interest you, if your username relates to your interests.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165101/discussion-between-michael-roy-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Answer (score 0):

this means a pointer reference to itself. Before we copy other obj, we should know whether the two objects are the same. If same, we don't need do anything.

Comment: _"the same"_ Be careful with this ambiguous term. Equivalence and identity are important distinctions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `a` and `b` are of type `coord`, and a simple assignment `a = b` is performed, the `return *this` in the body of `coord &coord::operator=(const coord &)` returns a reference to `a`.

The effect of this is to permit chaining of assignments of `coord` objects.  For example,

```
a = b = c;
```

is equivalent to (since assignment is right to left associative)

```
a = (b = c);
```

The expression `b = c` therefore is therefore turned by the compiler into a call of `b.operator=(c)`, which returns a reference to `b`.    Similarly the assignment of `a` is turned into a call of `operator=()`, so the above is equivalent to

```
a.operator=(b.operator=(c));
```

which (assuming `operator=()` is correctly implemented to perform a member-wise assignment) assigns both `a` and `b` to `c`.    The reference returned by `a.operator=()` is, in this case, ignored by the compiler.

The `if (this == &other)` test is an old technique to handle self-assignment (e.g. `a = a`) as a special case (e.g. by doing nothing).   Such a thing is generally discouraged for various reasons, such as behaving differently if the `coord` type has a unary `operator&()`.  As noted by "Lightness Races in Orbit" in a comment to another answer, it is generally considered preferable to use the copy and swap idiom instead - refer for example to [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom/3279550).