# Would passing an object to a member function or a constructor be a good use for explicitly using a this pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, this

Would passing an object to a member function or a constructor be a good use of 
explicitly using a this pointer? such as a pass by reference?

```
 class Something
{
private:
    int m_data;

public:
    Something(int data ->&obj)
    {
        this->data = m_data;
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried googling your question?

Comment: It is useful whenever it is required. When you face that problem, you'll find out.

Comment: This is too broad

Comment: You mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492736/what-is-the-this-pointer

Comment: The question marked as duplicate is only *half* the answer. The other half is when you need to assign or pass a pointer to the current object.

Comment: @KillzoneKid no, not too broad at all. It's only slightly broader than the question about when to use `this->`.

Comment: Consider a class such as Point with a function such as circle(int radius) that makes and returns a new Circle class. The Circle object needs to be told about where its centre is. How would you pass the central Point to the new Circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When is using the “this pointer” useful in a C++ program

When you need a pointer to the current object.

One of the most often usages of `this` that I have seen is to make self assignment a noop.

```
Foo& Foo::operator=(Foo const& rhs)
{
   if ( this != &rhs )
   {
      // Assign only when the objects are different
   }
   return *this;
}
```

I haven't seen this as much but you can do the same simplification for `operator==`.

```
bool Foo::operator==(Foo const& rhs) const
{
   if ( this == &rhs )
   {
      return true;
   }

   // Do the real work for objects that are different.
   // ...
}
```