# C++ - Is it possible to use the method of another class without inheritance?

Tags: c++, class

I'm fairly nooby at C++ but have this question that I hope makes sense:

Can a method in class B call a method within class A under these conditions:

- B cannot inherit from A
- you cannot create an object of A within B
- the method in A cannot be static

For example, can this be done by passing an object of A by reference to the method call of B.

My next question would be, what if an object of B was created WITHIN an object of A. How does A reference itself to pass to the method of object B?

An example of what I'm imagining:

```
class A;

class B
{
    int x = 10;
    int y = 10;
public:
    DoThis(A* obj);
};

B::DoThis(A* obj)
{
    obj->DoThat(int x, int y);
}
```

```
class A
{
public:
    DoSomething();
    DoThat(int x, int y);
};

A::DoSomething()
{
    B objB;
    objB.DoThis(this);
}

A::DoThat(int x, int y)
{
   std::cout << x << y;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    A* objA = new A;
    objA->DoSomething();

}
```

Comment: Regarding `A` passing instance of itself to `B`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492736/what-is-the-this-pointer

Comment: Regarding the main question: you sort of provided the code that does what you wanted, what is the problem here?

Comment: @orhtej2 For some reason when I write the actual code out it doesn't work. If there isn't anything obvious that I'm missing in the above then I might be making the error elsewhere, but your "sort of" makes me a unsure :)

Comment: What definition of "use" are you ... using?

Comment: Well you didn't specify any data type for `B::x` and `B::y` in your class definition. And you should forward declare `class A;` before the definition of `B`.

Comment: @Kaz To be speceific, **call** method in A but use variables initialized in B.

Comment: @Timo It was sort of pseudo code to explain the concept. But the types could be float for example. Fixing now.

Comment: Also, the declaration of `A::DoThat` is different from the definition.

Comment: @AndrewCina before posting, you should run your code to make it most bug free

Answer (score 1):

The only problem is that your code contains numerous rudimentary errors, like lack of type specifiers in declarations, lack of terminating semicolons, wrong order (using a class `A` before it has been declared), mismatches between calls and declarations and such.

Here is a patch to fix the problems. I also added a `,` (comma space) between the two numbers being output, and a terminating newline.

```
--- dothis-ORIG.cc  2019-09-18 14:13:15.002235916 -0700
+++ dothis.cc   2019-09-18 14:16:56.548099037 -0700
@@ -1,32 +1,36 @@
+#include <iostream>
+
+class A;
+
 class B
 {
-    x = 10;
-    y = 10;
+    int x = 10;
+    int y = 10;
 public:
-    DoThis(A* obj);
-}
-
-B::DoThis(A* obj)
-{
-    obj->DoThat(x, y)
-}
+    void DoThis(A* obj);
+};

 class A
 {
 public:
-    DoSomething();
-    DoThat();
+    void DoSomething();
+    void DoThat(int x, int y);
+};
+
+void B::DoThis(A* obj)
+{
+    obj->DoThat(x, y);
 }

-A::DoSomething()
+void A::DoSomething()
 {
     B objB;
     objB.DoThis(this);
 }

-A::DoThat(x, y)
+void A::DoThat(int x, int y)
 {
-   std::cout << x << y;
+   std::cout << x << ", " << y << std::endl;
 }

 int main()
```

Comment: It seems I'm getting some circular references in my headers then. I've searched around and tried to fix the issue, but I'm having no luck.