# cannot understand use of this parameter in making a class in c++

Tags: c++, tree

```
class Node {
public:
    int key;
    Node *parent;
    std::vector<Node *> children;

    Node() {
      this->parent = NULL;
    }

    void setParent(Node *theParent) {
      parent = theParent;
      parent->children.push_back(this); // I can't understand this.
    }
};
```

In the function setParent, in parent->children.push_back(this), why do we pass this as the parameter and what will it do?

Comment: [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this) is basically a pointer to the calling object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'this' pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492736/what-is-the-this-pointer)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'this' pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492736/what-is-the-this-pointer)

Answer (score 2):

The `this` pointer is a pointer to the object whose member function is currently executing. That line of code adds `this` node to its parent's vector of children. That makes sense because `this` node is one of its parent's children.