# class name as return type & use of this pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, this

I was learning about the `this` pointer, and I came across the below code. Can anyone explain what the code does? What does `*this` mean? Why does `setX()` have a return type as class `Test`? What is the purpose of placing `&` before `setX()` and `setY()`?

```cpp
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  
class Test 
{ 
private: 
  int x; 
  int y; 
public: 
  Test(int x = 0, int y = 0) { this->x = x; this->y = y; } 
  Test &setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; } 
  Test &setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; } 
  void print() { cout << "x = " << x << " y = " << y << endl; } 
}; 
  
int main() 
{ 
  Test obj1(5, 5); 
  
  // Chained function calls.  All calls modify the same object 
  // as the same object is returned by reference 
  obj1.setX(10).setY(20); 
  
  obj1.print(); 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: While learning from code samples can be helpful at times, as a beginner you should pick up a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and learn the basics first. For example learn about pointers and references. If you know how those work you should be able to understand the code by yourself.

Comment: By returning a reference to itself, it allows for a *fluent style* of C++ programming.  Like doing `test.setX(5).setY(6);`  (I am not a fan of *fluent style*, but some people really like it and some teams have it as part of their coding style guidelines.)  The reason why you need `*this` is because *references* were added to C++ long after `this` had already been introduced to the language.  If they had been added prior, `this` probably should have been a reference to the object instead of a pointer to the object.

Comment: `*this` dereferences `this` and will result in a `Test&` in this case. It's the same as if you have a pointer to anything else and dereference it. `int* a = new int; *a = 10; std::cout << *a; delete a;` - In this example `*a` returns/becomes an `int&`.

Comment: Best to read (and write) `Test &setX` as `Test& setX` since it is associated with the return type, not the function idenfitier.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the 'this' pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492736/what-is-the-this-pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following syntax:

```
obj1.setX(10).setY(20);
              ^^^^^^^^
              assigning y, returning the object
obj1.setX(10)
     ^^^^^^^^
     assigning x, returning the object

obj1
a successfully initialized object
```

---

In `Test& setX(int a)`:

```
Test& setX(int a) { x = a; return *this; }
```

When the call that function after creating an object of the class `Test` in the main code takes place, the `a` (which is a passed parameter by value) is assigned to `x` and then the entire object is returned by the help of `*this`.

Again, in `Test& setY(int b)`:

```
Test& setY(int b) { y = b; return *this; }
```

Same stuff happens here, `y` is assigned and once again, the entire object is returned itself as the return type is mentioned. In short words, `y` is assigned to `b`, `x` is assigned to `a` and in both cases, they returned themselves as the form of object.

---

The meaning of `*this`: dereference (`*` is called here the indirection operator, or, dereference operator, it gives the value stored at the memory address instead of a memory address) to `this` (which indicates the object itself).

Answer (score 2):

Pointer **this** is available to the class member functions. It is pointing to the object by which the function is invoked. **this** represents an object address and ***this** represents the object itself.